# Remove "this" callback in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a bit kotlin newbie and I'm trying to remove the callback instance inside the callback itself.

What I'm trying to achieve it's something similar to the following code.

```
private val myCallback = SomeInterfaceType {
   if(it.something) {
        someObject.removeListener(this@SomeInterfaceType)
   }
}
```

Of course it doesn't compile or else I wouldn't be asking here. So I ask, how to remove the callback from inside the instance of the interface?

**edit:**
the error is "inferred type is X but Y was expected.

**edit 2:** I just realized I've asked the wrong question, it's similar to it but not exactly a Interface.

The object I'm using have the following constructor/interface

`public open class Watcher<T> public constructor(call: (T) -> kotlin.Unit)`

so in reality I'm trying to reference the Watcher from inside the `call: (T) -> kotlin.Unit` to remove the listener.

Is that possible?

Comment: _"Of course it doesn't compile"_ So what is the _full, exact_ error message you're getting?

Comment: `someObject.removeListener(this)` . Check zsmb13's answer

Answer (score 14):

You need to use a full [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) syntax to refer to be able to refer to the instance itself:

```
private val myCallback = object: SomeInterfaceType() {
    override fun onSomeEvent() {
        if (it.something) {
            someObject.removeListener(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and as far as I tested here, that indeed is the correct answer for a `interface`. Please check my edit on the question, I just realized later that it's actually a `code: (T) -> kotlin.Unit` that I'm using. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

There's also a workaround: wrap the reference to `myCallback` into a lambda passed to a function that calls it (e.g. [`run { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html)):

```
private val myCallback: SomeInterfaceType = SomeInterfaceType {
   if (it.something) {
        someObject.removeListener(run { myCallback })
   }
}
```